# Can non-harmful eddy currents be used to heat water?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current, water, electromagnetic-induction

I think after 'googling' some web sources that eddy currents are strictly localized in a volume of iron surraunded by a loaded inductive coil so can not cause an electric shock to a person while the person touches a point of that iron that is farther from the coil if the iron piece is long enough.My oppinion is if they cannot be transferred to a person directly they also should not be transferred by means of water. So my question is as follows:can eddy currents be used to heat water passing through a hollow iron piece (pipe) and so be used as an instant induction water heater?(Ofcourse an iron surface should be treated with anti-corosive layer) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can. eddy current induction in hollow steel pipes is used to heat-treat the pipe and any liquid flowing through the pipe at the same time  is going to get heated up by contact with the pipe's walls.

Comment: There is no possible electric shock?